# Session Management when multiple requests are sent to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

The flow of the my code is:

html page1 -> servlet1 -> html page2 -> servlet2

Code for html page1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="xers?time=2">
    <button class="large-button">Morning Theory</button>
    </a>

    <a href="xers?time=1">
    <button class="large-button">Evening Theory</button>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

In servlet1 I am getting the value of time using getParameter function and I am storing the value in the session (HttpSession). After that I am going to another html page which then goes to servlet2. In servlet2 I am getting the value of time using session.getAttribute(). The problem occurs when I am running 2 or more instances of the servlet project. Lets say in the first instance I select morning theory, then the value of time becomes 2 and gets stored in session, in the second instance if I select evening theory then the value of time becomes 1 and gets stored in the session. But the problem here is that the second instance overwrites the value of time stored in session done by instance 1. So in this case the time value for the first instance also becomes 1 which should not happen. How do I prevent this from happening? As far as I know the sessions should be unique for every client.

I have tried multiple ways to solve the problem i.e by using request to store instead of session etc but nothing works. Can someone please help

Comment: This is indeed how sessions work. See abovelinked duplicate. Request scope must work, so you will have better chance in getting an answer to your problem if you instead ask about the problem you faced while trying request scope. Hint: #1 starter's mistake is that they send a redirect afterwards instead of forward.